# 0097 - faltando parênteses à direita. - Podem ajudar

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Sei que ja tem algumas tratativas aqui no forum a cerca deste erro 0097 - 
faltando parênteses à direita.. 
Eis o meu comando, podem me ajudar ?

```
select distinct Coalesce(Sum(Case When FI_TITULO.ABERTOQUITADO = 'Q' Then 0 Else (FI_TITULO.VLRNOMINAL - FI_TITULO.VLRPAGO) End) as sc_alias_0, 0) as sc_alias_1 
from FI_TITULO 
Right Join FI_CLIENTE On FI_TITULO.SEQPESSOA = FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA
Inner Join GE_PESSOA On GE_PESSOA.SEQPESSOA = FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA
Inner Join GE_PESSOACADASTRO On FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA = GE_PESSOACADASTRO.SEQPESSOA
where FI_TITULO.OBRIGDIREITO = 'D'
  and Coalesce(Sum(Case When FI_TITULO.ABERTOQUITADO = 'Q' Then 0 Else (FI_TITULO.VLRNOMINAL - FI_TITULO.VLRPAGO)End) = 2500000
```

Answer (score 2):

No `where` você não está fechando o `coalese`. Acredito que a ideia é validar o que é trazido no `select`, então ficaria assim:

```
select distinct Coalesce(Sum(Case When FI_TITULO.ABERTOQUITADO = 'Q' Then 0 Else (FI_TITULO.VLRNOMINAL - FI_TITULO.VLRPAGO) End) as sc_alias_0, 0) as sc_alias_1 
from FI_TITULO 
Right Join FI_CLIENTE On FI_TITULO.SEQPESSOA = FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA
Inner Join GE_PESSOA On GE_PESSOA.SEQPESSOA = FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA
Inner Join GE_PESSOACADASTRO On FI_CLIENTE.SEQPESSOA = GE_PESSOACADASTRO.SEQPESSOA
where FI_TITULO.OBRIGDIREITO = 'D'
  and Coalesce(Sum(Case When FI_TITULO.ABERTOQUITADO = 'Q' Then 0 Else (FI_TITULO.VLRNOMINAL - FI_TITULO.VLRPAGO)End) as sc_alias_0, 0) = 2500000
```

Comment: @ rLinhares Obrigado pela resposta.